# counting the rows for permutations of a join

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables - team_instance and player_instance where player_instance references team instance. I also have other tables - call them X,Y,Z - which reference player_instance.

What I want to do is join team_instance and player_instance with each of tables X,Y,Z and count how many  rows are returned for each.

I have this so far:

```
SELECT team_instance.id, COUNT(team_instance.id) * 3 AS dropkick_points
FROM team_instance
INNER JOIN player_instance ON team_instance.id = player_instance.team_instance_id
INNER JOIN dropkicks ON player_instance.id = dropkicks.kicker_id
WHERE dropkicks.success = true
```

The table dropkicks is X and I have used COUNT to add up the total number of rows returned (conditional on a value within dropkicks 'success' being true).

What I need to do now is this for the other tables Y,Z (which will not be multiplied by 3 but a different value) and then add all these values up into a single column.

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `INNER JOIN` is done before `SELECT` you will not be able to know the amount of the rows in each individual table since they have been joined. So what you can do is `COUNT` each one:

```
SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(X.id) * 1 FROM X ) 
     + ( SELECT COUNT(Y.id) * 2 FROM Y ) 
     + ( SELECT COUNT(Z.id) * 3 FROM Z )
AS dropkick_points
...
```

This returns the sum of  `(# rows in X * 1) + ( # rows in Y * 2) + (# rows in Z * 3)`

*Note* this is assuming that `id` is the primary key and is unique in the table. If you are unsure about the primary key or it's composite then you could replace `COUNT(X.id)` with `COUNT(*)`, this ensure you will get all the rows, but `*` is not as optimized.